# Error code 805a0194 when submitting an app review

Tags: store, app-review

I'm trying to submit a review for the app SEQR using my Nokia Lumia 920 with 8.1 Developer Preview. Whe I press submit I get this error message:

> There is a problem completing your request. Try again later.
>
> Inquiring minds may find this error code helpful: 805a0194

What is wrong with my phone?

Comment: Does this happen with any other apps, or just that one?

Comment: Just this one. Think it has to do with the region settings.

Comment: How are your phone's region and language set up?

Comment: I live in Sweden but I like to use Cortana. Yesterday I downloaded an app only available for the Swedish market and then I changed the region back to US to get Cortana back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Change the region of your phone to the region you used when you downloaded the app. When the regions are the same you'll be able to review the app.

#### Cause

This error occurs when the app you are trying to review is not available in the region your phone is set to.

This is probably what you did:

1. You found an app available in another region
2. You changed the region of your phone and downloaded the app
3. You later changed the region back (to a region in which the app is not available)
4. You tried to review the app.